# Differentiability of a Piecewise at x=1?

Tags: limits, derivatives

Is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x=1$?

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2,  & x \le 1 \\
x, & x>1
\end{cases}$$
So far I have determined that the function is continuous but I am unsure how to determine if left and right hand limits are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the definition of diferrentiabillity, that means $f$ is differential in $x_0$ iff
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=:f^{'}(x_0)
$$
exists. Here we have now if $h$ approaches zero from above
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to+0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}= \lim_{h\to+0}\frac{(1+h)-1}{h}=1
\end{align}
and from the other side
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to-0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}= \lim_{h\to-0}\frac{(1+h)^2-1}{h}= \lim_{h\to-0}\frac{2h+h^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to-0}(2+h)=2
\end{align}
and therefore we have
$$
1=\lim_{h\to+0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}\neq\lim_{h\to-0}\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{h}=2
$$
which means the limit does not exist and the function is not differentiable in $x_0=1$.